# Embedding raw html with fable feliz

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I want to embed a raw html "someRawHtmlDiv" string in the feliz markup. Any ideas how to do this?

```
#r "nuget: Feliz.ViewEngine"

open Feliz.ViewEngine

let someRawHtmlDiv =  "<div>
                something in here
                </div>"
     
let view = 
    Html.html [
        Html.head [ Html.title "Feliz" ]
        Html.body [
            Html.header [ prop.text "Feliz" ]
            Html.html someRawHtmlDiv // what goes here?
                
            ]
        ]
    
let document = Render.htmlDocument view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `prop.innerHtml` might give you what you want, although you can't combine it with other `Html` functions in the same element:

```ml
Html.html [
    Html.head [ Html.title "Feliz" ]
    Html.body [
        prop.innerHtml someRawHtmlDiv
        ]
    ]
```